# Edge loops problem + modeling by set of panes

Tags: edges

I'm beginner and I'm modeling Campana Factory. I already created tower. My 1st approach was to model 1 quarter of it then mirror it in X & Y axis and change front after that. But while modeling 1st quarter I have encountered problems with creating edge loops, it start to go crazy like here:[image]

So I just created that quarter with few levels of panes (usually cubes with 4 faces deleted except 2 for walls), then mirrored, then changes to front to add doors etc. Vertices not merged, but I can repeat/duplicate few sections from lower levels. Eventually joined those objects to form 1 object for future moving, rotating and scaling:[image]

Can it be left that way? Is that good technique?

Comment: If there's a single plane on your first screenshot, then clearly the topology is wrong, perhaps the vertical line, where the new loopcut yellow indicator drops down, is actually a very thin column of faces. But maybe it's just a screenshot made at an angle at which the faces, where the yellow line drops down, are not visible. Either way, I'd suggest to aim for segments of topology with vertically equal bottoms and tops (so yellow lines of loop cuts would be perfectly horizontal), so that when you apply various modifiers, you will get consistency across a given height.

Comment: OK. 1st screenshot is 1 quarter without modifiers, 2nd is full length after modifiers. Aim is to be it as left half in 2nd screenshot. There was extrusion in white area in 1st or in green bricks area in 2nd screen + another close to windows.